# Способ хранения идентификаторов блоков AdMob для Debug и Release сборок

Tags: android, admob

Подскажите где лучше хранить идентификаторы рекламных блоков AdMob для разных сборок приложения (Release и Debug) дабы не править каждый раз при релизе. Читал что хранят в strings.xml, также в build.grandle.

Answer (score 1):

Это примерно так делается:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue "string", "banner_id", "123123gfdg"    
    }
    debug {
        resValue "string", "banner_id", "321321gdfg"    
    }
  }
```